# Sending the notification without a button Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to make an app which downloads (periodically) data from a server and notifies the user when downloaded.

I tried to use Toast message, but I need a notification in the status bar. 
I used some sample code from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) which notifies after clicking the button. But I need to send the notification without clicking the button.

The most precise question is

> how to call the sendNotification after ".execute" in "run" function, which arguments should I use in sendNotification(?what here?) ?

This `h.postDelayed` stuff is in `OnCreate` method.

Here is the code:

```
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new WebServiceHandler()
                    .execute("http://maciekb94.cba.pl/");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pobrano dane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //sendNotification();
                    h.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    },delay);
}

public void sendNotification(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            //Uri.parse("http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    // END_INCLUDE(build_action)
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (build_notification)

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_new_message);

    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Set the notification to auto-cancel. This means that the notification will disappear
    // after the user taps it, rather than remaining until it's explicitly dismissed.
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentTitle("Pobrano dane");
    builder.setContentText("Wejdź by je zobaczyć");


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    //END_INCLUDE(send_notification)
}
```

Comment: share the same code which you implemented

Comment: Call `sendNotification` method wherever you need to show the notification. Please post more code for better help.

Comment: With which arguments should I call this method?

Comment: @Maciekb you can remove arguments from your method and make it empty and call it inside onPostExecute() of your asynctask

Comment: @Karan That's it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Maciekb that's it way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Place:

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

In the run function. Notify updates or creates the Notification. 
See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Send your notification in onPostExecute() of your WebServiceHandler() task.

```
public class WebServiceHandler extends AsyncTask{

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

            ..........

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: But the notificationManager and builder are in the sendNotification function and in the postExecute it says "Cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: call your sendNotification() function in onPostExecute().